# IIS 7.5 can't access file from managed code

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

I am working on a project that is click-once deployed from an IIS 7.5 web server.  After installing the parent application (i.e. setting up the IIS site) I am able to hit the url for the click-once app's config file from a remote box.
HOWEVER, when I attempt to do the same thing from my app (and the stub app below), I get a 401 Unauthorized.

What is the difference between hitting the URL from IE, and from a .NET app?
The file and directory itself have full control granted to everyone on the webserver at the moment, and I am an admin on the box.  We are using Windows Authentication with NTLM only.

Thanks,
-Bob

Here is the stub app that produces the 401 - Unauthorized when on the doc.Load() line.  I can hit the same URL successfully from IE and open the file...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Config Test");
        string filename = "http://dev-rs/myClient/myClickOnce/myApp.config.xml";
        Console.WriteLine(filename);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded");
        Console.WriteLine("Inner Text : " + doc.InnerText);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establish the principle:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

XMLDocument does not support passing credentials when loading from a URL.  Instead load from a WebRequest stream and set the credentials on the request before the load.

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(filename);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: that did the trick! Noticed I wasnt doing that on a subsequent webService call from app...had to set the credentials there with CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials as well.